# How to handle the bind exception with @ExceptionHandler

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

My requirement is to perform the server side validation for the form using Spring 3.0 and Hibernate Validator.Remember that I am submitting the form using AJAX call.My Controller class code is like below.

```
public ModelAndView generatePdfReport(@ModelAttribute("reports") @Valid ReportsCommand model, BindingResult result, ModelAndView modelAndView,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {


        if (result.hasErrors()) {

            throw new BindException(result);
        } 
        else{
           ...
           }
```

update...

```
   @ExceptionHandler(BindException.class)
   public @ResponseBody String handleException(BindException e,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
   {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        return e.getMessage();

   }
```

This is the Handler Method I placed in the controller.I used the @ResponseBody annotation but still it is showing the response in html format not in JSON format...
What is the wrong in my code..
And the below is the field I am validating

```
@Size(min = 2, max = 3, message = "calltype must between 2 to 3 Characters.")
    private String callType;
```

If I give size as more than three, it is entering into the if and throwing the exception.What I want is that, I want to handle this exception and return the json response.May be I can do this using @ExceptionHandler but don't know how.Or any other solution to resolve this problem also will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

#### import this package

```
import org.springframework.validation.BindException
```

#### not this

```
import java.net.BindException
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no automatic way to transform the binding errors to JSON. You should do that manually. You can do it in two places:

- inline - instead of  throwing BindException, generate the JSON and return it (using a custom ModelAndView that works with JSON, or by writing to the response)
- in an exception handler declared to handle `BindException`. You annotate a method of some (base) controller with `@EXceptionHandler(BindException.class)` and do the same transformation errors -> json as above

Comment: Hi thanks for giving the reply.Now i updated my controller class code with exceptiongandler method.Can you have a look into that.If i use the code like that i am getting the response as html format not as json format.Can you tell me what might be the wrong with my code...

Answer (score 4):

In my spring boot version(2.2.4.RELEASE), there is a method you can override under the class(MyCustomExceptionHandler) extended by `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`.

The method that you can use like that:

```
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleBindException(BindException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    logger.info(ex.getMessage());
    return super.handleBindException(ex, headers, status, request);
}
```

You can return ResponseEntity that includes related object. I just printed the exception message in the log as an example.

Answer (score 3):

Just to give an update about the current version of Spring:
If you just simply throw a BindException(bindingResult) from your conroller method, then spring will return a detailed JSON reply with information about all the validation errors:

Method in @RestController

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/ballot", method = POST)
public BallotModel postBallot(@Valid @RequestBody BallotModel newBallot, BindingResult bindingResult) throws BindException {
    log.trace("=> POST /ballot "+newBallot);
    log.debug("ballotService="+ballotService);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        log.trace("   ballot is invalid: "+bindingResult.getAllErrors());
        throw new BindException(bindingResult);  // this generates a cool error message. But it should be documented :-)
    }

    return newBallot;
}
```

HTTP reply

```
{
  "timestamp": "Sep 20, 2016 11:57:07 AM",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.validation.BindException",
  "errors": [
    {
      "field": "voteOrder",
      "bindingFailure": false,
      "objectName": "ballotModel",
      "codes": [
        "NotNull.ballotModel.voteOrder",
        "NotNull.voteOrder",
        "NotNull"
      ],
      "arguments": [
        {
          "codes": [
            "ballotModel.voteOrder",
            "voteOrder"
          ],
          "defaultMessage": "voteOrder"
        }
      ],
      "defaultMessage": "may not be null"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Validation failed for object='ballotModel'. Error count: 1",
  "path": "/ballot"
}
```

Comment: then there is no need to write another method to catch the thrown exception?